# Определить виды суффиксов

Tags: словообразование, морфология, суффиксы, морфемика

Ск аза ла; суффиксы: А - словообразующий; Л - формообразующий.

Ти ше; суффикс: Е - формообразующий.

Проч итан ный; суффиксы: А - словообразующий; НН - формообразующий.

Ск аз ав; суффиксы: А - словообразующий; В - формообразующий.

С каз ака; суффиксы: А - словообразующий; К - формообразующий.

Доб рей ший; суффикс: ЕЙШ - формообразующий.

Читай; суффиксы: АЙ - словообразующий; Ø - формообразующий.

Миленький; суффикс: ЕНЬК - формообразующий.

Comment: @elenaalisa, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Миленький - суффикс: ЕНЬК - СЛОВОобразующий.

Сказака - это что за слово?
Может, СКАЗКА? Суффикс: К - СЛОВОобразующий.

Остальное верно. Читай: АЙ - словообразующий, потому что входит в словообр. основу наст. времени, а формообраз. нулевой.